# The default user/password (admin/admin) don't work when I install Superset using Docker Compose in Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: apache-superset

Following the [official documentation](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-using-docker-compose), I installed Apache Superset via docker on my Windows PC and it worked without any problems. But when I installed it on Ubuntu Server 22.04, the default user/password (admin/admin) don't work and I can't login, and I don't know how to change it via terminal.
Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

I have tried running these commands:

```
docker exec -it superset_app /bin/bash
superset fab reset-password --username admin --password admin
```

But they don't work.

I want to be able to login in Apache Superset installation on the server

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version your are running, you likely affected by the new default of `TALISMAN_ENABLED`. You can try to change this config to `false`.

You can find the list of [breaking changes here](https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/UPDATING.md). There is an [GitHub issue related to your question here](https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/24579#issuecomment-1646360332).